# Using webjobs to run powershell script shows "The request is not supported" error

Tags: powershell, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to run following powershell script using webjobs, but receive an error. Local run **works** just fine.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
   -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ `
   -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```

The output from webjob run details is:

> ERR ] New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server 
>    outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : WS-Management 
>   cannot process the request. The operation failed because of an HTTP error. The 
>   HTTP error (50) is: The request is not supported. . For more information, see 
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>    + $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange 
>   -ConnectionUri ht ...
>    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationAborted,PSSessionOpenFailed

Is it possible to connect to remote Exchange online server from azurewebsites webjob and "do something" there?

Comment: Check your authentication mechanism. I don't think Exchange supports basic authentication on those management sessions.

Comment: It works nice when running from local machine, so I suppose the problems are not in attributes, but in the cmdlet and its interaction with azure.